# LINUX error in scripting with shell| awk: syntax error near line 1

Tags: shell, unix, awk, solaris

i'm trying to build a small script that cut only the file names i want and move them to another mos file.
when the grep is executing i get the error (look down the code)

```
Last MO:  4592. Loaded 4592 MOs. Total:  4593 MOs.
pls enter RBS number eg LTE8824,: LTE1976

L1976> l cd

New directory: /home/yesumim

L1976> l cd /home/yesumim/LTE_INT/

New directory: /home/yesumim/LTE_INT

L1976> $path = `ls |grep $RbsNumber`

$path = LTE1976_6083

L1976> l echo $path

LTE1976_6083

L1976> l cd $path

New directory: /home/yesumim/LTE_INT/LTE1976_6083

L1976> !ls *BB* |grep -v "xml"|awk '{print "run " $0}'|sort>command.mos

awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

L1976> run commands.mos

L1976>

L1976>

L1976>

L1976> confb-

L1976> l cat commands.mos



L1976>
```

if i'll take only this line:

```
!ls *BB* |grep -v "xml"|awk '{print "run " $0}'|sort>command.mos
```

and try to execute it i will get the following:

```
L1976> l cat command.mos

run 01_L1976_TN_SCTP_PTP_L16_for_BB_v1.mos
run 02_L1976_ENodeBFunction_MME_EUtranFrequency_L16_for_BB_v1.mos
run 03_L1976_1_Radio_Config_Optic_2x2_L16_for_BB_v1.mos
run 03_L1976_3_Radio_Config_Optic_2x2_L16_for_BB_v1.mos
run 04_L1976_1_SectorCarrier_EUtranCellFDD_L16_for_BB_v1.mos
run 04_L1976_3_SectorCarrier_EUtranCellFDD_L16_for_BB_v1.mos
run 10_L1976_Feature_Qos_SUP_External_L16_for_BB_v1.mos

L1976>
```

and this is the whole script code:

```
confb+

lt all
$RbsNumber = readinput(pls enter RBS number eg LTE8824,: )
l cd
l cd /home/yesumim/LTE_INT/
$path = `ls |grep $RbsNumber`
l echo $path
l cd $path
!ls *BB* |grep -v "xml"|awk '{print "run " $0}'|sort>command.mos
run commands.mos


confb-
```

can someone tell me why i get this error while i'm scripting and while i'm running the cmd as he is it's OK?

Comment: what are these `l` you have after the prompt? Also, try to provide a [mcve], now there is way too much code in here for a thing that can probably be shown in 5 lines.

Comment: Look,
I'm working at a cellular company and using amos shell to connect BTS (Base Station)
When I typing commands in shell and I'm connecting mobile site I must start command in "l".
You can treat it like it does not exist
If I am not connected to any site, but only to the system I do not use "l" to write commands

Comment: i have added the script code to the main post

Comment: Ah wait you are probably using an old awk. Instead, call `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`.

Comment: Yes, he's definitely trying to use old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris). Wonder why he tagged it with Linux then? AFAIK old, broken awk isn't available on Linux.

Comment: so what should i use to write data to the start of each line to a file?

Comment: and you are said correct, i'm using solaris, i fixed the tag.

Generally,
i'm just trying to use grep, add prefix called "run " to each line and write all this to a file but it always said error on the awk command:

awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1